# Do I need to send common variables in every get call in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a bunch of pages in my express project. The navigation (which occurs in all pages) contains the user's name if they're logged in. Do I need to pass the user variable every time to each page or is there a better way of doing this?
For instance:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Index!', user: req.user });
});

router.get('/helloworld', function(req, res) {
  res.render('helloworld', { title: 'Hello World!', user: req.user });
});
...
```

Comment: Check out [`res.locals`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.locals).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned by @robertklep in the comments, I'll expand on it a bit.

There's `app.locals` which sets variable for all requests. You can set it outside your router. This is usually for setting site-wide variables like title of the site.

```
app.locals.title = 'My Site'
```

Then there's `res.locals` which is for setting variables for the specific requests. An example would be to set the user object.

`res.locals` actually over-rides `app.locals` in that if a property is found on both then the one on the `res.locals` takes precedence. For example you can have a site-wide title and then a specific title for a specific route.

```
app.locals.title = 'My Site'
app.get('/index' function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.title = 'Index | ' + app.locals.title;
    ...
});
```